# How to only accept ArrayBuffer as parameter

Tags: typescript, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I have a class which accepts an array buffer parameter in the constructor like this:

```
class Test {
    public constructor(buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Problem is the `ArrayBuffer` type is a pretty small interface which also accidentally matches typed arrays (which are not array buffers). So my class can also be constructed with a typed array as parameter. So both calls are valid for the compiler:

```
new Test(new Float32Array([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]).buffer);  // <-- Correct usage
new Test(new Float32Array([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]));         // <-- Wrong usage
```

To prevent using my API in the wrong way I want the compiler to reject passing typed arrays to the constructor. Anyone knows a nice little trick how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, found a solution:

```
type StrictArrayBuffer = ArrayBuffer & { buffer?: undefined };
```

It matches a real `ArrayBuffer` because it has no `buffer` property and it doesn't match a typed array because this type has a `buffer` property which doesn't match the type `undefined`.